# Cross comparison of duplicates in multiple columns using COUNTIF / SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I am currently attempting to cross-compare two different columns in Excel, where I only want a flag to occur when duplicates are found in both column A and Column B.

Summary: Column A contains ID numbers. Column B contains birthdays. I want to make sure that if there are multiple rows containing the ID number, that the birthday column also matches. If only 1 of the conditions match, it is ignored.

Example:

| ID number | Date of Birth | Duplicate? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | *01/01/2000* | No |
| *DEF987* | *01/01/2000* | No ​ |
| *DEF987* | 04/06/1966 | No |
| ***GHI456*** | ***03/03/2001*** | **Yes** |
| ***GHI456*** | ***03/03/2001*** | **Yes** |
| JLK654 | 08/07/1996 | No |

I've tried the following example formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(A3,A:A))*ISNUMBER(FIND(B3,B:B)))`, where it will count 1 for no match, and 2 for a match, although it still returns a match if only the birthday is duplicated, not both.

Is there any alternative way to facilitate such a functionality, please? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just `COUNTIFS()`? >> `=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$7,A2,B$2:B$7,B2)>1,"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this formula for the column header named **Duplicate?**

This gives you the count where it is more than once, and wrapping it up within an IF Logic to check if its TRUE to return Yes otherwise No

Formula used in cell C2 & Fill Down

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A:$A,$B:$B,$B:$B)>1,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Using entire column references for the `criteria` range is completely unnecessary. What's more, if you attempt that formula in Office 365 it will practically crash Excel, since it will attempt to spill into more than 1 million cells.

Comment: Since OP has not mentioned, how large is his data is so i considered that, also i see OP has used the entire column, there fore we can assume, it works for him, without crashing, i never faced such an issue, but i prefer using named ranges !

Comment: @JosWoolley I am using O365, i really never faced, !

Comment: I assure you that just one instance of your formula is having to process more than 2 million cells. What's more, if you're filling down anyway, why are you referencing an entire column for the `criteria`? Makes no sense.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, did OP mentioned, the last row of his data, i don't see anywhere, so its in general, OP can easily fix it, and moreover Excel crashes even if you are using entire column or not, and it not only depends on using entire column but relevant factors, ! Thank You Sir.

Comment: You're missing the point. You have told the OP to put the formula in cell C2 and to fill down. But in that case the criteria references should contain a single cell reference. And I disagree with you completely: a formula which references one million cells is far less efficient than one which references 100.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, i just tested with `500000` rows of data it did not spilled it only spills when you take rows in to account, so this one works without any issue however what you said is fine --> Works without spilling - `=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A:$A,$B:$B,$B:$B)>1,"Yes","No")` , doesnt works because of `SPILL ERROR` --> `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$500000,$A$2:$A$500000,$B$2:$B$500000,$B$2:$B$500000)>1,"Yes","No")`

Comment: Your first formula is still processing `more than 2 million cells`. My machine freezes when I have just 10 cells containing that formula.

Comment: @JosWoolley it seems now, you are deliberate to prove someone wrong here, which i never do, anyways, however i never faced such an issue with `2 million or 5 million cells`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241787/discussion-between-mayukh-bhattacharya-and-jos-woolley).

Comment: Although this answer is correct, the point made by @JosWoolley is also correct. The formula is indeed attempting to process 2 million cells worth of data, which leads to system hangs while it processes.

I made a modification of this answer to account for that, which is this: 

`=IF(COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:A,(COUNTA(A:A))),INDEX(A:A,(COUNTA(A:A))),INDEX(B:B,(COUNTA(B:B))),INDEX(B:B,(COUNTA(B:B))))>1,"Yes","No")`.

This performs the same solution you provided me with, while restricting the range to just the number of filled cells instead of the whole sheet. Thanks for the help, it's appreciated!

Comment: @Wisp i dont think its working for me, could show me a screenshot,

Comment: @Wisp could you check once sine this doesn't return a range --> `=INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))` it gives `ZERO` for criteria range as well as criteria, if you share, it will be good for me to learn, its not working!

Comment: Let's be clear here: in functions such as `COUNTIF(S)`, `SUMIF(S)`, etc., the `criteria_range` parameter can be of arbitrary length with very little detriment to performance. However, this is not at all the case with the `criteria` parameter. This is an important difference. So, for example, `=COUNTFIS(A:A,A1)` and `=COUNTFIS(A1:A10,A1)` will be virtually identical in terms of efficiency, though there will be vast difference between `=COUNTFIS(A:A,A1)` AND `=COUNTFIS(A:A,A:A)`.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, i agree, but sir the one which Wisp has menitoned that doesnt work, could you explain how is it working for him.

Comment: More to the point, in this case, unless you are using Office 365, there is absolutely no need to reference more than a single cell for the criteria parameter, i.e. `IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)>1,"Yes","No")`, placed in row 2 and then copied down, is correct and efficient. If you have Office 365, it's true that you can pass a spill array as the criteria parameter, but then you should be very careful to limit the size of that array, e.g. `IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2:A10,B:B,B2:B10)>1,"Yes","No")`. But note that this only applies to Office 365.